# Nuxt.js multi-tenancy (SaaS) system dynamic 'static' folder change

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js, multi-tenant, saas

Is there a way how to correctly approach this problem?

I need to have multiple users where each is having his own database and his own folder with static files.

This is one app controlling each user separately based on given URL.

I need some mapping from "static/img.jpg" -> "static/user-123/img.jpg" so If someone calls "userdomain.com/img.jpg" I'll get content from (i.e.) "static/user-123/img.jpg"

Where should I define this? In express file settings? And how?

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with nginx handling this problem. I don't know If it is possible to make it through the app.